# ReactJs How to check user authenticated and sessionID generated by ExpressJs

Tags: reactjs, express, sessionid

I have a Nodejs application creating a session when the user gets authenticated.
I see that Expressjs stores the sessionID in a cookie which at the moment is HttpOnly and the session info itself is stored server side.

How to check that the user is authenticated and there is an open session from ReactJS (that is, browser side)?
I think that the only way is to try and access that sessionID? What is a good way of implementing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The register or login should respond with the necessary user information to the client side on React so that user information could be stored in the application state (Redux/Flux). The sessionId stored as HttpOnly cookie by express server is solely for the purpose of Express to uniquely distinguish a browser session.

Ideally you would need another API as well to return the user information which at the Express server side should read the sessionId cookie and return with the currentUser information back to the client. Suppose, you login and the user information is stored in the UI application state, and when you refresh the browser, this application state would get flushed off. In such a scenario, this API would help to restore the application state with the current logged in user information. Hope this helps.